# Searching a df column in R based on athor column

Tags: r

df

```
App1             App2
PS(id-123)       id-345
HR(id-345)       id-789
Web(id-567)      id-123
Trading(id-789)  id-345
```

etc

Columns in data frame are not ordered or may or maynot match the same row values. For example, on row one, PS(id-123) does not match id-345. Values on App1 and App2 freely input.

I need to go throguh App2 and if the value on App2 matches the value between Parentheis in Apps, need to replace that value in App2 with the value from App1.

This is what my final df should look like:

```
App1             App2      App3
PS(id-123)       id-345    HR(id-345)
HR(id-345)       id-789    Trading(id-789)
Web(id-567)      id-123    PS(id-123)
Trading(id-789)  id-345    HR(id-345)
```

search App1 based on value from Apps2 and  if matched put the value in App3 column?

Any ideas how can approach this in R?

Comment: I think you might have described this as "looking up the item in App1 that has the match inside the parens to the value in App2". You didn't really want to replace anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is short and works with your current data:

```
transform(df, App3 = App1[sapply(App2, grep, App1)])
#              App1   App2            App3
# 1      PS(id-123) id-345      HR(id-345)
# 2      HR(id-345) id-789 Trading(id-789)
# 3     Web(id-567) id-123      PS(id-123)
# 4 Trading(id-789) id-345      HR(id-345)
```

To make it a little more robust, you could replace `App2` above with `paste0("(", App2, ")")`, also replace `sapply` with `vapply` and the expected output: `integer(1)`.

**Edit:**

Since it appears some ids do not have a match, an approach based on `match` might be more appropriate:

```
transform(df, App3 = App1[match(App2, sub(".*\\((id-.+)\\)", "\\1", App1))])
```

where `sub(".*\\((id-.+)\\)", "\\1", App1)` is used to extract the interesting information from the `App1` column.

Comment: @flodel, I get this error:   invalid subscript type 'list', any ideas?

Comment: That probably means you don't have a single match per id. Is it possible an id has more than one match or no match at all? If so, you should reflect it in your example. I'll work on an edit.

Comment: @flodel, yes, that is exactly right. App1 and App2 in the df are independent of each other. Wheever I see App2 text in App1, App3 should have App1 entry. There may be cases where App2 may not be in App1.

Answer (score 1):

flodel's is a more elegant but this might help understand the steps.

```
> idx <- sapply(dat$App2, function(x) grep(x, dat$App1) )
> dat$App3b <- dat$App1[idx]
> dat
             App1   App2            App3           App3b
1      PS(id-123) id-345      HR(id-345)      HR(id-345)
2      HR(id-345) id-789 Trading(id-789) Trading(id-789)
3     Web(id-567) id-123      PS(id-123)      PS(id-123)
4 Trading(id-789) id-345      HR(id-345)      HR(id-345)
```

Comment: I triedd this dat$App3b <-data$App1[idx], is giving me this error: invalid subscript type 'list'